# Standby problems vs specific kernel version - Kernel regression?

Tags: kernel, updates, kubuntu, suspend, bug-reporting

In the last year my PC suffered from increasing problems while going into standby. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it failed. Each kernel update added to the failure chances. For some time I could work around that by using s2ram. Finally, after updating to Kubuntu 20.04, standby stopped working completely.

Recently, after installing one more kernel update, standby suddenly worked perfectly fine. The following update killed standby once more. This is a list of the three kernels on my system:

- 5.4.0.53 - Standby fails
- 5.4.0.54 - Standby works
- 5.4.0.56 - Standby fails

I have three questions:

1. How can I configure Kubuntu to not offer newer Kernel updates (via Discover and 'apt dist-upgrade') until the issue is resolved?
2. I would like to test if the newest available kernel also suffers from the problem. What is the newest compatible kernel I can (manually) install on Kubuntu 20.04 (e.g. using Mainline tool)?
3. How and where should I report the regression to get it fixed permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the answers to your questions:

1. You can run `sudo apt-mark hold linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` to stop kernel upgrades.

If it is 18.04 with a HWE kernel, then the command is

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
```

2. You can install any stable kernel or even a release candidate from [Ubuntu kernel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).
3. Report kernel bugs by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: Regarding 2.: The PPA includes kernels up to 5.10.1. So I can basically install any kernel version? Does this mean the reason why Kubuntu 20.04 distributes 5.4 kernels instead of newer ones is stability not compatibility?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a rolling release. It is not supposed to get the latest kernels. Using mainline kernels is not recommended with Ubuntu unless there is no other way to get something working.

Comment: I am aware of that. What I don't know is *why* it isn't recommended. What problems should I expected to happen?

Comment: It is not tested and can cause all sorts of problems. The system is not supposed to work with mainline kernels.